# Datatable server side scripting to handle large number of data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I want to use datatable plugin to handle large number of data. Right now I want to implement "server side processing in datatables"
[server side scripting](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html)

I did not use ajax much so I am unable to understand how to fetch record in my table through ajax file in this scenerio. Here is my HTML and javascript:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.3/css/scroller.dataTables.min.css">


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >

   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "server_processing.php"
    } );
} );

</script>

</head>

<body>

<body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <table id="example">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

            </table>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here I made server_side scripting file and unable to understand what to do:

```
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "phwdata");

$query = "select * from persons";
$query2 = mysqli_query($link,$query);
while($fetch= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){;
$id = $fetch['id'];
$name = $fetch['name'];
$position = $fetch['position'];
$description = $fetch['description'];

}
?>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you really go through the docs? I don't think so. Check under the `AJAX` tab and see the format you should be returning. You should match your return data with what the `API` says.

Comment: any example or link for the guide as I am unable to understand how to get and return record in ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your server side code to this and try: to check sample of server side go to [Here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) and click on Server-side Script and see.

**This will give sample data.**

```
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "phwdata");
$query = "select * from persons";
$query2 = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($query2);
$columns=array("draw"=>1,"recordsTotal"=>$num_rows,"recordsFiltered"=>$num_rows);

while($fetch= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){;
$columns["data"][]=array($fetch['id'],$fetch['name'],$fetch['position'],$fetch['description']);
}

echo json_encode($columns);
```

**For your pagination to work change your server side code to this:**

```
$table = 'persons';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id';
$columns = array(
        array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),
        array( 'db' => 'name',  'dt' => 1 ),
        array( 'db' => 'position',   'dt' => 2 ),
        array( 'db' => 'description',     'dt' => 3 ),
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
        'user' => 'root',
        'pass' => '',
        'db'   => 'phwdata',
        'host' => 'localhost'
);
require( 'ssp.class.php' );// https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php

echo json_encode(
        SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

Comment: yes data is showing but filter and pagination is not working here.

Comment: Yes for the pagination and filter too you need to use LIMIT functions & make SQL to find the results as per the filters.

Comment: @SmitMehta  check the second part for pagination.

Comment: I changed it to this and it is giving me the error of : DataTables warning: table id=datatable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: you have to include `ssp.class.php`. get it from the comment added in code section. second part of code in working fine with my different table while posting i have changed the column names and table to match with yours.